# Python RegEx expression to extract numeric characters AND other special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to develop a regex expression that could convert something like:

```
"< 0.071U ug/L"
```

To

```
"<0.071"
```

Basically, the expression would only keep numeric values, `"."`, and `"<"`.

I would like to apply this to a pandas dataframe using `.extract()`

This works for the floating point numbers:

```
r'(\d*\.?\d+)'
```

But I cannot figure out how to also keep `"<"`

Comment: Does the "<" always come before the floating point number?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bC3DRT/1 is a simple brute force method that might work for you depending on the variation in data.

Comment: Why don't you also match it? `(<\s*\d*\.?\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/9CRR7s/1

Answer (score 1):

There is a space between `<` and the number, and if you do not mind this whitespace in your output, you can go on using `Series.str.extract` with

```py
df['col'].str.extract(r'(<\s*\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Tez9t/3). *Details*:

- `<`  - a `<` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

However, you may simply remove all chars other than digits, dots and less than signs with `Series.str.replace`:

```py
df['col'].str.extract(r'[^<.\d]+', '')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Tez9t/2).

The `[^<.\d]+` pattern is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches one or more chars other than `<`, `.` and digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "< 0.071U ug/L"

print (re.sub(r"([^0-9-<.]+)","",s))
```

Output:

```
<0.071
```